# Error in optimization problem with ompr package in R

Tags: r, optimization, ompr

I am trying to code an optimization problem with the ompr package in R. I tried out a few examples and was now comfortable with trying to implement a simple version of my problem.

I get multiple errors if I try to change the code I have. This is the code I used. The first error i get:

```
Error in set_objective(sum(skater_proj[i] * skaters_lineup[i]) + sum(goalie_proj[f] *  : 
  unused arguments (i = 1:num_skaters, f = 1:num_goalies)
```

Here the code:

```
model <- MIPModel() %>% 
  add_variable(skaters_lineup[i],i = 1:num_skaters,type = "binary") %>%
  add_variable(goalies_lineup[i],i = 1:num_goalies,type = "binary") %>%
  add_constraint(sum(goalies_lineup[i]) == 1, i=1:num_goalies)%>%
  add_constraint(sum(skaters_lineup[i]) == 8, i=1:num_skaters)%>%
  add_constraint(sum(centers[i]*skaters_lineup[i]) <= 3, i=1:num_skaters)%>%  
  add_constraint(sum(centers[i]*skaters_lineup[i]) >= 2, i=1:num_skaters)%>%  
  add_constraint(sum(wingers[i]*skaters_lineup[i]) <= 4, i=1:num_skaters)%>%  
  add_constraint(sum(wingers[i]*skaters_lineup[i]) >= 3, i=1:num_skaters)%>%   
  add_constraint(sum(defenders[i]*skaters_lineup[i]) <= 3, i=1:num_skaters)%>%  
  add_constraint(sum(defenders[i]*skaters_lineup[i]) >= 2, i=1:num_skaters)%>% 
  add_constraint(sum(salary_skater[i]*skaters_lineup[i]) + sum(salary_goalie[d]*goalies_lineup[d]) <= 50000 , i=1:num_skaters,d=1:num_goalies)

set_objective(sum(skater_proj[i]*skaters_lineup[i]) + sum(goalie_proj[f]*goalies_lineup[f]),i=1:num_skaters , f = 1:num_goalies)
```

If I change the objective to:

```
set_objective(sum(skater_proj*skaters_lineup) + sum(goalie_proj*goalies_lineup))
```

i get this problem:

```
Error in set_objective_(model, expression = lazyeval::as.lazy(substitute(expression),  : 
  object 'skaters_lineup' not found
```

I don't know how this can happen, I defined the variable before.

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should try the `sum_expr` function from ompr instead of the base `sum` function because it allows you to set the summation index to sum across. The second objective you listed, won't work even with the `sum_expr` call because you have to provide the index values .